# ESP32 Tasks vTaskDelay: expected one execution of a loop but getting multiple

Tags: freertos, esp32

I'm trying to work with tasks on a ESP32;

```
loop(){
xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(SendCanBusMessageToCharger, "SendCanBusMessageToCharger", 1000, NULL, 3, NULL, 0);

  }

  void SendCanBusMessageToCharger(void *pvParameters) {
    CAN_frame_t tx_frame;
    tx_frame.FIR.B.FF = CAN_frame_ext;
    tx_frame.MsgID = 0x1806E5F4;
    tx_frame.FIR.B.DLC = 8;
    tx_frame.data.u8[4] = 0x00;
    tx_frame.data.u8[5] = 0x00;
    tx_frame.data.u8[6] = 0x00;
    tx_frame.data.u8[7] = 0x00;

    while(true) {
      tx_frame.data.u8[0] = highByte(outputvoltage);
      tx_frame.data.u8[1] = lowByte(outputvoltage);
      tx_frame.data.u8[2] = highByte(outputcurrent);
      tx_frame.data.u8[3] = lowByte(outputcurrent);
      ESP32Can.CANWriteFrame(&tx_frame);
      Serial.println("CAN message sent to charger");
      vTaskDelay(1000);
    }
```

I expected to get one "CAN message sent to charger" message on the serial port each second, but I'm getting:

```
12:11:15.866 -> CAN message sent to charger
12:11:15.866 -> CAN message sent to charger
12:11:15.866 -> CAN message sent to charger
12:11:15.866 -> CAN message sent to charger
12:11:15.866 -> CAN message sent to charger
12:11:15.866 -> CAN message sent to charger
12:11:15.866 -> CAN message sent to charger
12:11:15.866 -> CAN message sent to charger
12:11:15.899 -> CAN message sent to charger
12:11:15.899 -> CAN message sent to charger
12:11:15.899 -> CAN message sent to charger
12:11:15.899 -> CAN message sent to charger
12:11:15.899 -> CAN message sent to charger
12:11:15.899 -> CAN message sent to charger
12:11:15.899 -> CAN message sent to charger
12:11:15.899 -> CAN message sent to charger
12:11:15.899 -> CAN message sent to charger
12:11:15.899 -> CAN message sent to charger
12:11:15.899 -> CAN message sent to charger
```

Around 8 messages each second. Also tried vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS( 1000 )) but result is the same. I don't really see what I'm doing wrong here... Building with the latest Arduino IDE and ESP board definition. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yep well that was stupid.... I put the task creation in the loop instead of the setup and was staring at the code for so long I didn't see it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that the vTaskDelay waits for ticks, not ms, and you does not convert it properly.
Solution:
vTaskDelay(1000/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);